# Is it possible to speicify the windows 10 store app installation path

Tags: installation, uwp, store

when we deploy the windows 10 store app, it installed to
“C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\product_1.5.35.0_x64__2p2rtd4hb3axg\myproduct.exe”

it it possible to have to installed to
“C:\Program Piles\WindowsApps\product\myproduct.exe”
or
“C:\Program Piles\WindowsApps\product_x64__2p2rtd4hb3axg\myproduct.exe”

we only need it install the latest version, so I want the install path exclude the version number
is it possible?

Regards,
Gordon

Comment: No possible without sideload

Comment: how to do this with side load? if that is possible, I will still consider it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lindexi mentioned, this is not possible to do that if you install the app from the store.

Comment: so it is possible if using the sideload? how ?

Comment: No, there is no document mentioned about this.

Comment: @GordonLi Yes, as RoyLi-MSFT mentioned, it is not document mentioned this, but we can do that by mklink with win32 installer.